# How to add a volume/volumeMount from helm chart?

Tags: installation, kubernetes-helm, grafana, volume, grafana-loki

I am trying to install official helm chart of grafana/loki-stack on my (on premis) kubernetes cluster, I have persistent volume claim to add loki/promtail for persistence, but how to add ?

For the moment I have installed in namespace monitoring with this 2 command:

```
helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
```

and

```
helm -n monitoring install grafana/loki-stack
```

Thank you all for the answers

Comment: Are you writing this chart yourself, or are you merely trying to deploy Grafana with persistence enabled?  "Deploy" questions aren't really about programming, and might be better asked on another site like [devops.se] or [sf].  Please clarify if you are actually writing the chart yourself though.